# What is the cURL -s option?

Tags: curl

Here's an example:

```
curl -s acme:acmesecret@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
```

It looks like it is used to specify that the URL contains the `acme:acmesecret` (authentication credentials) part?

### Reference

As [Charles pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656248/what-is-the-curl-s-option/45656317#comment78270716_45656248), these types of questions are very easy to answer with [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl%20-s).  So if you ended up here you will probably have other similar questions and explainshell is the way to go.

Comment: Have you tried reading the man page?

Comment: It's also covered by http://explainshell.com: See https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+-s+acme%3Aacmesecret%40localhost%3A9999%2Fuaa%2Foauth%2Ftoken

Comment: (Frankly, I object to this line of questions simply because it doesn't scale: If we had one question along these lines for every possible option to every possible command, the site would be cluttered with useless cruft).

Comment: Well - this is probably a meta type discussion.  I agree with you, but only because explainshell is perfectly suitable for this type of questioning.  There's nothing wrong with being able to find quick answer to succinct question on SO in general.

Comment: BTW @CharlesDuffy - the regex tag, when used, causes a popup that contains helpful links, such as [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).  It would be great to have something like this for questions tagged with curl as well...just in case you have any pull with the SO developers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It means silent.  Here's an [explainshell link](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=curl+-s+).  Plan on using that a lot in the future!